# Did the actors sing for Rock of Ages?

Tags: rock-of-ages

In Rock of Ages, did the actors themselves sing for the film, or did other people sing and they dub over the actors?  Or was it a mix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this **New York Times** review](http://movies.nytimes.com/2012/06/15/movies/review-rock-of-ages-a-musical-starring-tom-cruise.html?partner=rss&emc=rss&_r=0):

> **All the songs are sung**, mostly without shame or distinction, **by the actors themselves...**

The director *Adam Shankman* [wouldn't have cast](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303830204577446563074429858.html) *Tom Cruise* if he hadn't been able to sing:

> *"[Tom Cruise and I] made a gentlemen's agreement that if the vocal thing doesn't work out, we'll just shake hands and look for something else"*

*Tom Cruise* ended up training for over 4 months. And he [insisted](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/anne-hathaway-surprising-singing-stars/story?id=16467442#1) that:

> there be no digital enhancements of his voice either